# How to call a function when custom toolbar is clicked in Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to create a custom toolbar. Here is my code:

```
toolbar:[{
    text: "Go to Add User Page",
    className: "k-grid-custom",
    imageClass: "k-add"
}],

function createUser(){
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

I want to call the function named createUser when this button(custom toolbar) is clicked. How to make it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function test(e){
      return '<a class="k-button" href="#" id="toolbar-add_user" onclick="test_fn()">Add User</a>';
 };
function test_fn(){
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
};
 toolbar:[{
        name:'add_user',
        template:'#= test()#'
}],
```

1. First i had to make a function to be able to customize the button and add an onclick event.
2. Then i had to make a new function to listen to the event.

Comment: Why you return the template using a function?

Comment: So this doesn't work?

    toolbar:[{
            name:'add_user',
            template:'<a class="k-button" href="#" id="toolbar-add_user" onclick="test_fn()">Add User</a>'
    }]

Comment: I use the exact same technique in one of my apps, no problems. Perhaps you mucked up the syntax somewhere.

Comment: but if i have edit mode and redirect to another edit page so that i want that edit mode id and that id i am not getting any idea how to get custom edit mode create using onclick and window.location java script function

Comment: it gives an error because you cant use href="#" since the hashtag cant be used like that in a template. if you were to use href="javascript:;" it would work.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a unique class to the button and then use that class to bind to the click event.

```
toolbar:[{
    text: "Go to Add User Page",
    className: "myCustomClass",
    imageClass: "k-add"
}],

$(".myCustomClass").click(function() {
    alert("Click!");
});
```