# Adding custom button to KendoGrid Toolbar Issue

Tags: kendo-grid, toolbar

Hi I've added a button to the toolbar of my KendoUI Grid, but I have a couple of issues, I'm hoping someone can assist with.

1. I've tried to add one of the kendo web icons next to the button but it doesn't render.
2. When I click the button in the toolbar I see the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sendEmail is not defined.

I don't understand why it isn't seeing my function. Just for testing purposes I'm displaying an alert until it sees it.

```
toolbar: [
            { name: "create", text: "Add" },
            { template: "<input type='button' class='k-button' value='Email Users' onclick='sendEmail()' />",
              imageclass: "k-icon k-i-pencil" }
        ]

function sendEmail() {
   debugger;
   alert('Send Emails');
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: My guess would be that function sendEmail() is inside the block where you define the Grid. Make sure that function is in it's own code block

Comment: I made sure that it was outside of where the grid is defined. I have it at the bottom of my $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: Here is a publication with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954911

Comment: After a bit of further searching I found a way using the following method to trigger the click event. `{ name: "email", className: "emailUsers", text: "Email Users" } $(.emailUsers).click(function() { alert('Send Emails');

Comment: @user721126 life saver! Setting the 'className' and binding the event yourself should be an answer! The click binding simply does not work for me, no matter what I try - including the well accepted answer below

Answer (score 4):

You can Use as below:

```
 toolbar: [
 {
    name: "Add",
    text: "Send Email",
    click: function(e){alert('Send Emails'); return false;}
 }
],
```

Comment: Amazingly, not even this works for me. The click event doesn't fire

Comment: actually, only kendoTreeList can apply the click, which is exactly the your provided solution

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you would need to return the function that you want to occur on click. Like this:

```
 template: '<a class="k-button" href="\\#" onclick="return toolbar_click()">Command</a>'
```

[The documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-toolbar.template)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

1. you must define your grid in variable
2. initializing grid and add your button in toolbar option
   toolbar: [{ name: "myButton", text: "this is your button text" }]
3. after initializing write this code to find button and add function:

> grid.find(".k-grid-toolbar").on("click", ".k-grid-myButton", function (e) {
>                                 alert("it's work") ;});

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to use this. Please use below example.

```
  toolbar: [
       //{ template: kendo.template($("#k-tmpl-toolbar").html()) },
       { name: "Add", template: kendo.template("<button class='k-button k-button-sm k-rounded-md k-button-solid k-button-solid-primary' onclick='AddNewRecord()'>Add New</button>") },
       { name: "search" },
       //{ name: "create", title: "New" },
   ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Is your function sendEmail() initialized in document.ready or $(()=>{}); if not you will have to initialize it or else you could use this way 
add a id for the button and write this in your document.ready (remove the onlcick from the button tag).
`$("#examplebuttonid").click(()=>{
//write your code in here
});`